# Performance: One table vs multiple tables (generated programatically) for the same logical entity?

Tags: java, database-design

I want to ask for any suggestions for an architecture I can implement for a Java app I need to create (initial thoughts below).

It is supposed to be a local Swing application for tracking financial aspects of multiple construction sites. Excel-like but with a few additional features like mailing data etc.

After some thinking, I came up with an idea of using a Derby database with a separate table for clients, another one for categories of products used and multiple "ConstructionX" tables, each containing records for a different construction site, created dynamically via JDBC.

That last part is what I'm most concerned about as it doesn't really feel like a good solution *programatically* but it does so *pragmatically*.

I don't really have much experience building applications like this so here comes my question: Is there any better way I could design this database? I'm open for suggestions (please don't post it on TheDailyWTF).

(I originally asked this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099712/java-app-using-derbydb-design-ideas) and was redirected here)

As a side note (as someone on SO suggested something like this too): I originally planned to create just one "Construction" table which would hold records for *all* construction sites where each record would be tagged with a construction site number it refers to (possibly forming a relation to a table holding all sites). However, I was worried about times of running "SELECT" statements (when displaying all records just for one specific site). Can anyone confirm it'd be a better solution here?

Comment: You cannot avoid select statements. Just make sure you have the tables appropriatelly indexed.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova Oh, I wanted to say that I believe running SELECT on separate tables would be more time efficient than running SELECT WHERE  on one table with lots of records.

Comment: Shouldn't we change the tittle to "One table vs multiple tables for the same logical entity?" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Creating separated tables for the same entity based on a domain value is generally a bad idea.**

[image]

[image]

**Talking about CONNSTRUCTION and CONSTRUCTION_SITE:**

- Make sure the tables are apropiatelly indexed
- CONSTRUCTION has a PK
- CONSTRUCTION_SITE has a PK
- CONSTRUCTION has a FK pointing to CONSTRUCTION_SITE

There will be an index for every PK and every FK.
The database engine will take care of, as fast as it can, filter out the rows you want. **That's what database engines are for.**

As they say: *"Premature optimization, etc."*

[image]

Comment: So turns out the original approach was much better. Thank you so much for the detailed answer and for simplifying my work :)

Answer (score 0):

The basis that I was taught was that if there is any enumeration that you will need then it should probably be defined as the primary key in a table and then used as a foreign key.